# Pagination in mvc5

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Can anyone help me?
I am using default pagination system in asp.net mvc5 EF.
Here is my code

```
public ViewResult Index(int? page)
{
    var students = from s in db.Students
                   select s;
    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
    int pageSize = 5;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

It's working fine, but I think every time it takes all data from the database, and then show in pagination.
When I click at page one then it load all data and shows only data for the first page. If every time it loads all data for every page click then it's not efficient. Can someone clarify if this code is correct for paging or how to only load the paged range from the database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you take all data. I did it like this:

```
var students = (from s in db.Students
               select s orderby s.LastName).Skip((page ?? 1)* 5).Take(5);
```

or using lambda expression

```
var students = db.Students.OrderBy(x=>x.LastName).Skip((page ?? 1)* 5).Take(5)
```

Comment: sorry, the skip function should be `(page ?? 0)` because for the first page you should skip nothing.